# Snowflake unloading structured data into semi- structured file format

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking to unload data in snowflake, is it possible to unload relational structured data into a semi-structured format like JSON?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It is documented here: [Unloading a Relational Table to JSON](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-unload-considerations.html#unloading-a-relational-table-to-json)