# How to create a Snowflake semi-structured OBJECT from tabular data?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, hierarchy

Let's say that I have a basic hierarchy in Snowflake:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES 
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'A', 1),
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'A', 2),
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'A', 3),
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'B', 4),
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'B', 5),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'A', 1),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'A', 2),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'A', 5),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'B', 3),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'B', 4)) 
      AS test_hierarchy ("DATE", "PARENT", "CHILD")
```

| DATE | PARENT | CHILD |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-23 | A | 1 |
| 2023-06-23 | A | 2 |
| 2023-06-23 | A | 3 |
| 2023-06-23 | B | 4 |
| 2023-06-23 | B | 5 |
| 2023-06-26 | A | 1 |
| 2023-06-26 | A | 2 |
| 2023-06-26 | A | 5 |
| 2023-06-26 | B | 3 |
| 2023-06-26 | B | 4 |

I would like to **write a SQL query in Snowflake** that transforms the tabular data into an object, or combination of objects, of the sort that is described in their [Semi-Structured Data documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/semistructured-intro).

The desired output might look roughly like this:

```
{
    "2023-06-23": [
        {"parent": 'A',
         "children": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
        },

        {"parent": 'B',
         "children": [ 4, 5 ]
        }
    ],
    "2023-06-26": [
        {"parent": 'A',
         "children": [ 1, 2, 5 ]
        },

        {"parent": 'B',
         "children": [ 3, 4 ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is it possible to construct such an object in Snowflake without exporting and re-importing the data? How would I use Snowflake's semi-structured utilities to accomplish this?

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65166749/snowflake-unloading-structured-data-into-semi-structured-file-format), I can see that [OBJECT_CONSTRUCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_construct) gets me part of the way there. It looks like some combination of [OBJECT_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_agg) and [ARRAY_AGG](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg) could also do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT`, `OBJECT_AGG` and `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
WITH test_hierarchy AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM (VALUES 
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'A', 1),
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'A', 2),
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'A', 3),
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'B', 4),
          ('2023-06-23'::DATE, 'B', 5),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'A', 1),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'A', 2),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'A', 5),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'B', 3),
          ('2023-06-26'::DATE, 'B', 4))
),
step_1 AS (
  /*
  Use OBJECT_CONSTRUCT to initialize a Snowflake object from each row in the result set.
  
  Pass the ARRAY_AGG expression as a value argument to OBJECT_CONSTRUCT, in combination with 
  GROUP BY, to collect the children into an array for each parent on each date.
  */
  SELECT
      "DATE",
      OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
          'PARENT', "PARENT",
          'CHILDREN', ARRAY_AGG("CHILD")
      ) AS OBJECT_EACH_PARENT_PER_DATE
  FROM test_hierarchy
  GROUP BY
    "DATE",
    "PARENT"
),
step_2 AS (
  /*
  Use ARRAY_AGG in combination with GROUP BY to collect the parent objets into an array for each date.
  */
  SELECT
    "DATE",
    ARRAY_AGG("OBJECT_EACH_PARENT_PER_DATE") AS ARRAY_ALL_PARENTS_PER_DATE
  FROM step_1
  GROUP BY
    "DATE"
),
step_3 AS (
  /*
  Use OBJECT_AGG to map each date to its corresponding array in a single object.

  GROUP BY is implied since there is only one column.
  */
  SELECT
    OBJECT_AGG("DATE", ARRAY_ALL_PARENTS_PER_DATE) AS PARENT_CHILD_MAPPING_BY_DATE
  FROM step_2
)
SELECT PARENT_CHILD_MAPPING_BY_DATE
FROM step_3;
```

Output:

```
{
  "2023-06-23": [
    {
      "CHILDREN": [
        4,
        5
      ],
      "PARENT": "B"
    },
    {
      "CHILDREN": [
        1,
        2,
        3
      ],
      "PARENT": "A"
    }
  ],
  "2023-06-26": [
    {
      "CHILDREN": [
        3,
        4
      ],
      "PARENT": "B"
    },
    {
      "CHILDREN": [
        1,
        2,
        5
      ],
      "PARENT": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```